# How to join two lists, if one is a tuple with multiple lists, into a dictionary…

Tags: python, list, dictionary

...by taking only the items that are present in the first list?

```
countries = ['PAN','ARG','NGA','KOR','SRB','BIH']
country_data = [
    ('arg', 'Argentina', 'SouthAmerica', 41.2238883972168),
    ('geo', 'Georgia', 'Asia', 4.231660842895509),
    ('kor', 'South Korea', 'Asia', 49.5528564453125),
    ('swz', 'Swaziland', 'Africa', 1.2028429508209229),
    ('cog', 'Republic of the Congo', 'Africa', 4.386693000793457),
    ('srb', 'Serbia', 'Europe', 7.291436195373535),
    ('pan', 'Panama', 'NorthAmerica', 3.643222093582153),
    ('ita', 'Italy', 'Europe', 59.72980880737305),
    ('dma', 'Dominica', 'NorthAmerica', 0.07143999636173247),
    ('nga', 'Nigeria', 'Africa', 158.57826232910156),
    ('bih', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Europe', 3.722084045410156)]

countries = [item.lower() for item in countries]
Input1 = countries
Input2 = country_data
for elm2 in Input2:
for elm1 in Input1:
    if elm2[key[1]] == elm1[key[1]]:
        break
else:
    Input1.append(elm2)
```

I started by making the elements in the list countries into a lower case so I can compare them but when I try to fetch the data I get an error. What would be a better way of turning the two lists into a dictionary with only the key values of the list countries?

Comment: If you give sample output then it makes easy to understand

Comment: Add more information. What's your expected output? And what error did you get?

Comment: What is your desired output? Your elm1 is a string, so it's not clear what you are trying to compare when you call elm1[key[1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
countries = ['PAN','ARG','NGA','KOR','SRB','BIH']
country_data = [
('arg', 'Argentina', 'SouthAmerica', 41.2238883972168),
('geo', 'Georgia', 'Asia', 4.231660842895509),
('kor', 'South Korea', 'Asia', 49.5528564453125),
('swz', 'Swaziland', 'Africa', 1.2028429508209229),
('cog', 'Republic of the Congo', 'Africa', 4.386693000793457),
('srb', 'Serbia', 'Europe', 7.291436195373535),
('pan', 'Panama', 'NorthAmerica', 3.643222093582153),
('ita', 'Italy', 'Europe', 59.72980880737305),
('dma', 'Dominica', 'NorthAmerica', 0.07143999636173247),
('nga', 'Nigeria', 'Africa', 158.57826232910156),
('bih', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Europe', 3.722084045410156)]


filtered_countries = [country for country in country_data
                      if country[0].upper() in countries]
print(filtered_countries)
```

output:

```
[('arg', 'Argentina', 'SouthAmerica', 41.2238883972168), ('kor', 'South Korea', 'Asia', 49.5528564453125), ('srb', 'Serbia', 'Europe', 7.291436195373535), ('pan', 'Panama', 'NorthAmerica', 3.643222093582153), ('nga', 'Nigeria', 'Africa', 158.57826232910156), ('bih', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Europe', 3.722084045410156)]
```

Comment: would it be possible to find the most common Continent among the Nations in both the lists using filters ?

Comment: create a list with the continents, i.e. instead of `country` it would be `country[1][1]` and then pass this to [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)